# How to turn off Auto highlight text in Vim editor?

Tags: vim, typedef, highlight, vim-syntax-highlighting

[image: Vim text editor]
In VIM text editor, everytime whenever I type ''typedef '', it gets highlighted automatically. How to fix this?
I want to turn off word highlighting property in vim.

Comment: Read the `vim` documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the "highlight search" flag on and the last search was for `typedef`. You can turn the flag off with `:set nohls`.

You can inspect all settings with `:set all`.

You can read the help for highlight search with `:help hls`.